# Can nested react components have different props?

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react.js and I just started reading a book that showcases nested components and shows how to pass an attribute to the child element. This is the example.

```
var GreetingComponent = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
  return <div>Hello {this.props.name}</div>;
}
});

var GenericComponent = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
  return <GreetingComponent name={this.props.name} />;
}
});

React.render(<GenericComponent name="World" />,
document.getElementById('container'));
```

As the book says "Starting from a top-level attribute on the GenericComponent, you can pass this attribute
by using this.props to the child element GreetingComponent." and this is why "Hello World" is rendered.

But, what if I want, for the sake of argument, the same structure, but I want every components to have a different prop value, like

```
var GreetingComponent = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
  return <div>Hello {this.props.anotherName}</div>;
}
});

var GenericComponent = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
  return <GreetingComponent name={this.props.name} />;
}
});

React.render(<GenericComponent name="World" anotherName="Earth"/>
document.getElementById('container'));
```

Check it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/slevin/58u139vd/115/).

This is not working and nothing is rendered.

How can I have two nested components with different prop values? Please explain and help me understand.

Thank you.

Comment: You must have both properties in both components, e.g: https://jsfiddle.net/58u139vd/116/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `<GreetingComponent name={...} />` to work, `GreetingComponent` must have a `name` property.

Since `GenericComponent` renders `GreetingComponent`, you must pass the name to `GenericComponent` as a property, called `greetingName` for instance, so that it will pass it to `GreetingComponent` as `name`.

Now, you want `GenericComponent` to have a name of its own, so you must give it a second prop.

See a solution here: https://jsfiddle.net/5kk90t0k/.

Comment: Thank you for your time. Nice answer.